# Use of checking in

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Consider the scenario where I have fever and someone pings me - **Just checking up on you if you are fine**

Is the reply - **Thanks for checking in. I am good now** correct. I am mainly confused about the use of *checking in* is that even a valid English sentence.
Any better way to express the same.

Comment: We can probably offer a better answer if we have a little more detail.  What is it about "checking in" that concerns you?

Comment: The concern is if it's proper English. Grammatically correct

Comment: I don't see checking-in as a proper word in online dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a valid sentence.

It comes from a phrasal verb *check in* which [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/check_in) (#5) *pay a short visit, make a phone call to see how someone is doing* .

> I just wanted to **check in** after your accident. How are you recovering?

> My son **checks in** regularly **with** me when he's travelling.

Answer (score 1):

To *check in* is to report your presence to some organisation that is expecting you; for example, at a hotel where you have reserved a room, or at the airport when you have booked a flight. It is not the same as *checking up on* someone (asking if they are OK).

You might answer "Thanks for checking up on me", "Thanks for enquiring", or "Thanks for getting in touch".